# pgfplots graph with secondary y-axis not same width as without secondary y-axis

Tags: pgfplots, width, axis

In pgfplots, how can I make a graph with secondary y-axis to be the same width as the graph without secondary y-axis? I am already specifying the same width, but clearly in the output they are of different width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

% 1st graph
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \pgfplotsset{set layers}
    \begin{axis}\[
        width = 0.8\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        axis y line* = left,
        title = {1st Graph},
        \]
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}\[
        width = 0.8\textwidth,
        scale only axis,
        axis y line* = right,
        axis x line = none,
        \]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    % 2nd graph
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \centering
    \begin{axis}\[
        width = 0.8\textwidth,
        title = {2nd Graph},
        \]
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
    \end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Hi, welcome. Hint: `scale only axis`

Comment: How were you ever able to compile that with `\[` to start options

Comment: @hpekristiansen Probably not that way in the original. That happens if you by accident paste code into the alt text of an included image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
axis y line*=left,
title={1st Graph},
]
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
axis y line*=right,
axis x line=none,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
title={2nd Graph},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two graphs with same width]

Comment: Magnificnent! Problem solved! Thanks a lot both!